Lilypond double clef
Does anyone know, how to put the soprano and the alto clef right before the treble clefs, just like in the image below?

I've been trying to figure out a way to solve this, for some time now, but the only thing I was able to come up was
\clef soprano \clef treble
but if you do this the soprano clef simply won't show.
If you could write me a code that reproduces the image above it would be really nice.

To understand why the command \clef soprano followed by \clef treble do not produce two clefs, one has to think on the clef as a certain property (which does not have a duration) which is modified by the command. You can modify it several times but only the last change is visible.

I think this could work but honestly I don't know how to remove the incipit time signature.
\score {
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \new Staff {
      \set Staff.instrumentName = ""
      \incipit { \clef soprano s16  }
      {  \clef "treble"  b'2 cis''2 d''1 }
    }
    \new Staff {
      \set Staff.instrumentName = ""
      \incipit { \clef alto s16 } 
      { \clef "treble" e'1 d' }
    }
  >>
}
\layout {
  incipit-width = 1.2\cm 
  \context { \Staff \remove "Time_signature_engraver" }
}



Thank you so much! Removing the time signature from the incipit is actually really easy: yu just have to add \omit Staff.TimeSignature.
